# Error : 'Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed' in building catkin_make(ROS workspace)

Tags: linux, simulation, ros

Im'a newbie in ROS and simulation program. I am trying to build the ROS workspace.

-Specifications:

- OS-Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, ROS-melodic

My goal is successfully to install simulation for erp-42. The following is the code
I entered before.

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-serial ros-melodic-velodyne-* ros-melodic-pcl-* ros-melodic-geodesy ros-melodic-ros-control ros-melodic-map-server ros-melodic-move-base ros-melodic-twist-keyboard
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install keyboard Sphinx


mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/jdj2261/ERP42-ROS.git
cd ~/catkin_ws
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
catkin_make
```

The following is the error code.

```
eunji@eunji-900X3T-900X3U:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
```

Base path: /home/eunji/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/eunji/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/eunji/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/eunji/catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "cmake /home/eunji/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/eunji/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/eunji/catkin_ws/build"

.
.
.
.
.
(omission)
Scanning dependencies of target driver_nodelet
[ 63%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/packages/erp42_sensors/erp42_velodyne/velodyne_driver/src/driver/CMakeFiles/driver_nodelet.dir/nodelet.cc.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/etc/erp42_detector/laser_detector/CMakeFiles/laser_detector_gui.dir/src/displays/segment_visual.cpp.o
[ 64%] Linking CXX shared library /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libobstacle_extractor.so
[ 64%] Built target obstacle_extractor
Scanning dependencies of target velodyne_node
[ 64%] Linking CXX executable /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/erp42_driver/erp42_driver_node
[ 64%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/packages/erp42_sensors/erp42_velodyne/velodyne_driver/src/driver/CMakeFiles/velodyne_node.dir/velodyne_node.cc.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcanbasic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ERP42-ROS/packages/erp42_driver/CMakeFiles/erp42_driver_node.dir/build.make:169: recipe for target '/home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/erp42_driver/erp42_driver_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/erp42_driver/erp42_driver_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4110: recipe for target 'ERP42-ROS/packages/erp42_driver/CMakeFiles/erp42_driver_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ERP42-ROS/packages/erp42_driver/CMakeFiles/erp42_driver_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 65%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/packages/erp42_sensors/erp42_velodyne/velodyne_driver/src/driver/CMakeFiles/velodyne_node.dir/driver.cc.o
[ 65%] Linking CXX shared library /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libobstacle_tracker.so
[ 65%] Built target obstacle_tracker
[ 67%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/etc/erp42_detector/laser_detector/CMakeFiles/laser_detector_gui.dir/src/panels/scans_merger_panel.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/etc/erp42_detector/laser_detector/CMakeFiles/laser_detector_gui.dir/src/panels/obstacle_extractor_panel.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/packages/erp42_sensors/erp42_velodyne/velodyne_driver/src/driver/CMakeFiles/driver_nodelet.dir/driver.cc.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/etc/erp42_detector/laser_detector/CMakeFiles/laser_detector_gui.dir/src/panels/obstacle_tracker_panel.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/etc/erp42_detector/laser_detector/CMakeFiles/laser_detector_gui.dir/src/panels/obstacle_publisher_panel.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object ERP42-ROS/etc/erp42_detector/laser_detector/CMakeFiles/laser_detector_gui.dir/laser_detector_gui_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 71%] Linking CXX shared library /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libndt_omp.so
[ 71%] Built target ndt_omp
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/velodyne_driver/velodyne_node
[ 71%] Built target velodyne_node
[ 71%] Linking CXX shared library /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libdriver_nodelet.so
[ 71%] Built target driver_nodelet
[ 71%] Linking CXX shared library /home/eunji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/liblaser_detector_gui.so
[ 71%] Built target laser_detector_gui
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

Could someone please help me figuring out the cause of these errors?
Thank you in advance

Comment: looks like the package `erp42_driver` fails to build. If you have clone this repo, make sure you are on the right branch.

Comment: *cannot find -lpcanbasic* --> Try to install the pcan drivers

Answer (score 0):

Could be three possible issues

1. you are not in the base package when using catkin_make
2. you may have some missing files

Try source yourworkspace/devel/setup.bash

then catkin_make